# Woocommerce Category Thumbnails in Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to create a custom loop to display all the WooCommerce categories on my site. It should be fairly simple but I'm having issues getting hold of the category thumbnails. No matter what I do, i seem to end up with the full sized images. Here's my code:

```
$args = array(
 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
 'orderby' => 'name',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'hide_empty' => false,
 'exclude' => '21'
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach( get_categories( $args ) as $category ) :
    $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $category->term_id,'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
    echo '<li><a href="'.$category->slug.'" class="label" title="' . $category->name . '">';
    if($image!=""):
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';
        endif;

    echo $category->cat_name.'</a></li>';
endforeach;
```

I've searched all over, but everyone else seems to get the correct images. I'm getting the full sized images as uploaded. Am I missing something here? Does anyone know of any reason why this might not be pulling in correctly? Could it be a theme issue?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `wp_get_attachment_url()` with [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) to get the thumbnailed sized image *(or specify the desired image size)*.

Also, you should use [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) to get the term URL instead of using the term slug.

So your code will be:

```php
$args = array(
 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
 'orderby' => 'name',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'hide_empty' => false,
 'exclude' => '21'
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach( get_categories( $args ) as $category ) :
    $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, 'woocommerce_thumbnail' );
    $term_link  = get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' );
    echo '<li><a href="'.$term_link.'" class="label" title="' . $category->name . '">';
    if( $image_html ):
        echo $image_html;
    endif;

    echo $category->cat_name.'</a></li>';
endforeach;
```

It should work as expected.

You can choose a different size from:

- `thumbnail`,
- `gallery_thumbnail`,
- `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail`,
- `woocommerce_single`,
- `single`…

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much for your help with this.